# Actual URL open redirect page in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Actual URL is

```
https://example.com/category.php?electronic=1&product=2440
```

I want when USER input `(https://example.com/category.php/electronic/product/laptop/dell/)` URL it open `(https://example.com/category.php?electronic=1&product=2440)` page

but on a browser, URL will not change means ( `https://example.com/category.php/electronic/product/laptop/dell/`) will display

I don't know ether I use base URI or database, Help me out with script what I use to achieve it.

Comment: This will either need to be done at the server level, or you will need to implement a framework such as laravel, codeigniter, etc that utilize custom routing, but that might be overkill for your particular situation as it would require rewriting everything you already have. Is this the only route you need to setup this way or will there be others?

Comment: Using modrewrite you could create a rule saying when traffic comes in with route `/category.php/electronic/product/2440` obtain and return response from `/category.php?electronic=1&product=2440 `. The issue with the way you are asking about `/category.php/electronic/product/laptop/dell/` is that the server will have no way of knowing that product `2440` is a `laptop` from `dell`. That must be determined using php by accessing your database.

Comment: modrewrite /category/electronic/product/laptop/dell/     ok!

Answer (score 0):

You could add an iframe element to the page with the src attribute set to the PHP page. Even if the iframe redirects, the address bar stays unchanged.